# Converting convex hull to binary mask

Tags: matlab, geometry, convex-hull

I want to generate a binary mask that has ones for all voxels inside and zeros for all voxels outside a volume. The volume is defined by the convex hull around a set of 3D coordinates (<100; some of the coordinates are inside the volume).

I can get the convex hull using [CONVHULLN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/convhulln.shtml), but how do I convert that into a binary mask?

In case there is no good way to go via the convex hull, do you have any other idea how I could create the binary mask?

Comment: You mean voxels, not pixels, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this problem using the [**DelaunayTri** class](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.html) and the [**pointLocation** method](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.pointlocation.html). Here's an example:

```
pointMatrix = rand(20,3);       %# A set of 20 random 3-D points
dt = DelaunayTri(pointMatrix);  %# Create a Delaunay triangulation
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(0:0.01:1);   %# Create a mesh of coordinates for your volume
simplexIndex = pointLocation(dt,X(:),Y(:),Z(:));  %# Find index of simplex that
                                                  %#   each point is inside
mask = ~isnan(simplexIndex);    %# Points outside the convex hull have a
                                %#   simplex index of NaN
mask = reshape(mask,size(X));   %# Reshape the mask to 101-by-101-by-101
```

The above example creates a logical mask for a 101-by-101-by-101 mesh spanning the unit volume (0 to 1 in each dimension), with a 1 (true) for the mesh points inside the convex hull of the 3-D point set.

Answer (score 2):

It's late here, so only a very sketchy suggestion:

1. With the points from your convex hull construct a Delaunay tessellation.
2. Using the pointLocation method of the DelaunayTri class test every point in your array of pixels.

I expect that this will be very slow, and that there are better solutions, if one comes in my dreams I'll post again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scan conversion problem.  Check out section 8 of [3D Scan-Conversion Algorithms for Voxel-Based Graphics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.81.1612&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The algorithm you want is the solid one, and is slightly simpler since you are voxelizing a convex polyhedron whose faces are triangles - each "voxel" run is bounded by two triangles.